# Can't use get method with Tkinter Text Widget

Tags: python, tkinter

I've got some troubles with Tkinter.
I'am trying to program a form which gets the name of a file and the content that the user wants to write in a text file. The code is shown below:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack()

bottomFrame = Frame(root)
bottomFrame.pack(side = BOTTOM)

def getInput():
    inputValue= textBox.get("1.0", "end-1c")
    print(inputValue)

fileName_ = StringVar()

textBox = Text(bottomFrame, height = 100, width = 100).pack(side = LEFT)

Label(frame, text = 'File name:').pack(side = LEFT)
Entry(frame, textvariable = fileName_).pack(side = LEFT)
buttonCommit = Button(frame, text = 'Write File', command = lambda: getInput())
buttonCommit.pack(side = LEFT)

root.mainloop()
```

When I run it and the form appears, I write something in the textbox and click the button to write print the content of the textbox in the Console, then the following message appears in the IPython Console:

> Exception in Tkinter callback
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter__init__.py", line 1699, in **call**
>       return self.func(*args)
>     File "C:/Users/Marcelo/Desktop/Web Develop/GUI Programming Python/p13.py", line 20, in 
>       buttonCommit = Button(frame, text = 'Write File', command = lambda: getInput())
>     File "C:/Users/Marcelo/Desktop/Web Develop/GUI Programming Python/p13.py", line 11, in getInput
>       inputValue= textBox.get("1.0", "end-1c")
>   AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'***

So, I cant print the content of the textbox in the console.
I found this code sample here, which works:

```
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
def retrieve_input():
    inputValue=textBox.get("1.0","end-1c")
    print(inputValue)

textBox=Text(root, height=2, width=10)
textBox.pack()
buttonCommit=Button(root, height=1, width=10, text="Commit", 
                    command=lambda: retrieve_input())
#command=lambda: retrieve_input() >>> just means do this when i press the button
buttonCommit.pack()

mainloop()
```

Comment: Not a duplicate of the indicated question because he assigns the result of `pack()` call that is **always** `None`. It is a duplicate of another question, can't find it easy.

Comment: Thats it. I am so thankful rioV8. Problem solved xD